# Graph Making from Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, graph, dataframe, time-series

i have a data frame called abc, that has rows of times (y direction) and columns of dates (x direction), the frame is made up of values.

what i need to do is create a graph by selecting a certain time, this graph needs to be dates vs the values in that row in the the dataframe. attached is a photo of the data

[example of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNjiL.png)

so i need to be able to create a graph by typing in say 9am and a time series graph will appear of a graph of jun,july,aug,sept etc... on the x axis vs 1,2,6,8,9 etc...on the y

and  then it would pull a different graph if i changed it to say 11am

Comment: What is your code thus far?

Comment: You can write a function to create the graph and then pass it subsets of the DataFrame (Series in this case) using [loc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very basic pandas functionality:
You can access the dataframe along the respective axis with the .ix operator

```
df=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(5, 4)),index=['9am','10am','11am','12pm','1pm'],columns=['jun','jul','aug','sept'])
# select '9am' and all [:] of the months
df.ix['9am',:].plot()
# select month and 9am  to 11 am
df.ix['9am':'11am','jun'].plot()
```

plot obviously draws the desired graph.